# Winston logger custom format overwriting timestamp

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I am using [winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) logger version 3.3.3 in a node app. I have a custom formatter for the output that looks like this:

```
const winston = require('winston');
const jsonStr = require('fast-safe-stringify');

const customFormat = winston.format.printf(data => {
    const { level, message, timestamp } = data;
    const args = data[Symbol.for('splat')];

    let strArgs = '';

    if (args) {
        strArgs = args.map(jsonStr).join(' ');
    } 

    return `${timestamp} ${level}: ${message} ${strArgs}\n`;
});

logger = winston.createLogger({
    level: 'debug',
    format: winston.format.combine(winston.format.timestamp(), customFormat),
    transports: [new winston.transports.Console()]
});

logger.log('debug', 'hi', 123, { a: 1, b: 'two' });
logger.log('debug', 'hi', { timestamp: 'this is bad' });
```

This lets me log things with multiple arguments of different types:

```
logger.log('debug', 'hi', 123, { a: 1, b: 'two' });
> 2020-11-11T19:01:46.942Z debug: hi 123 {"a":1,"b":"two"}
```

which is what I want. The problem is that if I log an object that contains a field called `timestamp` it overrides the `timestamp` field in the formatter.

```
logger.log('debug', 'hi', { timestamp: 'this is bad' } );
> this is bad debug: hi {"timestamp":"this is bad"}
```

So now the logger's timestamp is the string `"this is bad"`, which is bad. If I output the `data` parameter to the `printf()` method I see this:

```
{
    timestamp: 'this is bad',
    level: 'debug',
    message: 'hi',
    [Symbol(level)]: 'debug',
    [Symbol(splat)]: [ { timestamp: 'this is bad' } ] }
}
```

So you can see that the `timestamp` field is apparently being overwritten by the argument I'm passing in. It only happens if the third argument to the `log()` method is an object with a property called `timestamp`. So this is fine:

```
logger.log('debug', 'hi', 123, { timestamp: 'this is fine' } );

data: {
    level: 'debug',
    message: 'hi',
    timestamp: '2020-11-11T19:08:27.326Z',
    [Symbol(level)]: 'debug',
    [Symbol(splat)]: [ 123, { timestamp: 'this is fine' } ]
}
> 2020-11-11T19:08:27.326Z debug: hi 123 {"timestamp":"this is fine"}
```

Is this a bug in winston or is my `printf()` method not right?

Note I have a git repo that reproduces this issue [here](https://github.com/dland512/winston-formatting-issue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well a simple solution is to add a format or alias for the timestamp in `timeStamp.format()` as follows

```
logger = winston.createLogger({
    level: 'debug',
    format: winston.format.combine(
        winston.format.timestamp({ format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss' }), // can also alias
        customFormat
    ),
    transports: [new winston.transports.Console()]
});

logger.log('debug', 'hi', { timestamp: 'this is bad' } );

// outputs
2020-11-19 20:08:36 debug: hi {"timestamp":"this is bad"}
{
  timestamp: '2020-11-19 20:08:36',
  level: 'debug',
  message: 'hi',
  [Symbol(level)]: 'debug',
  [Symbol(splat)]: [ { timestamp: 'this is bad' } ]
}
```

coming to the explanation part I'm actually not sure why timeStamp gets overwritten it's quite strange.

Comment: Great, that works, thank you. But how did you know that specifying the format would fix it?

Comment: I did not it was a wild guess. I just went through one of my projects and found that I was providing date format. I added it to your snippet and it worked. here are some useful links https://medium.com/@ThreePotatoteers/winston-3-customize-timestamp-format-f510ce03b33d https://github.com/winstonjs/logform#readme

Answer (score 0):

Hey) I tried to reproduce your case but I could not reproduce. Try this code

```
const winston = require('winston');

const customFormat = winston.format.printf((data) => {
  const { level, message, timestamp } = data;
  console.log('data', data);
  const args = data[Symbol.for('splat')];

  let strArgs = '';

  if (args) {
    console.log('args', args);
    strArgs = args.map((argument) => JSON.stringify(argument)).join(' ');
  }

  return `${timestamp} ${level}: ${message} ${strArgs}\n`;
});

const logger = winston.createLogger({
  format: customFormat,
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console({
      level: 'debug',
    }),
  ],
});

logger.log('debug', 'hi', 123, { a: 1, b: 'two' });
// logger.log('debug', 'hi', { timestamp: 'this is bad' });
```

I checked, in first case timestamp is undefined. In second case I got timestamp: 'this is bad'. Winston does not pass his own timestamp to my log info.

Comment: That's because your `format:` property does not specify to use include the timestamp. Try this (sorry for the formatting): `const logger = winston.createLogger({ format: winston.format.combine(winston.format.timestamp(), customFormat), transports: [ new winston.transports.Console({ level: 'debug' })]});`

Comment: I went ahead and included a more complete code example and a git repo at https://github.com/dland512/winston-formatting-issue